# Unable to lock my stolen phone

Tags: calendars, find-my-phone

Hi my Lumina 520 has been stolen. I tried using the account.Microsoft/ device to locate or lock the phone. But nothing is working. The message being displayed is, try after some time. What could be the reason. How can I trace my device?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the user has switched your phone off or he has switched on the Flight mode. You probably won't be able to trace your phone.